# Validating many image urls in PHP WITHOUT downloading

Tags: php, image, url, curl, amazon-ec2

Note: This is a performance question

I have 20,000 image urls in mysql database, and I have a 1-minute interval cron running to check whether the image urls are valid and not broken. It's running on EC2 small. I've tried methods like @GetImageSize, checking headers and cURL, but they take up to 10mins for a job. I would like to find out if there's any method that doesn't involve downloading the images, and is extremely fast.

Here's some tests from the below suggestions (credits and kudos to them) on some **25 images in a loop**:

```
function method2($link){                               //45sec
    if (@GetImageSize($link)) {
        echo  "image exists ";
    } 
}

function method4($url){                            //13 sec
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    if(curl_exec($ch)!==FALSE)    {
            echo  "image exists ";
    }
}


function method3($filename){                          //20sec
    $h = fopen($filename, 'r');
    if ($h !== false) {
        echo 'File exists';
            fclose($h);
    }
}

function method5($url){                             //21 sec 
    if(@file_get_contents($url,0,NULL,0,1)){
        echo "image exists";
    }
}

function method6($url){                             //22 sec
    if (false === file_get_contents($url,0,null,0,1)) {
        echo "no ";
    }
}

function method1($url){                                //13 sec
    exec("wget --spider -v ".$url);
}
```

Comment: yea, I think it's not very realistic. But I'm still trying to find the fastest solution. They are stored in S3, not on webserver for performance reasons.

Comment: nope, not my bucket. an external party we are working with. But let's keep the discussion on the tech and not business layer.

Comment: The fastest method usually should be _parallelized_ `HEAD` requests. Sequential requests won't work, since you'd need response times of 3 ms to loop 20,000 requests within one minute. Expecting 3 ms responses when requesting URLs via Internet is completely inappropriate to reality (you'll get an avg of 100 ms, if you're lucky^^).

Comment: I see - thanks for the insights. Are you referring to [curl_multi_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) or smth else - and I'll test it out.

Comment: added the suggested solutions and the results for community's reference.

Answer (score 1):

If [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is "On" on your host, then you can `fopen` the URL and just close it without reading anything.

```
$h = fopen('http://www.example.com/img.jpg', 'r');
if ($h !== false) {
    echo 'File exists';
    fclose($h);
else {
    echo 'File does not exist';
}
```

---

Since you appear to be in touch with the owner of the target server, perhaps you should take another approach altogether. Call a script that you would host on the remote server, that returns a list of the files present in the file system. Then call this script from your end. This is certainly preferrable in any case, because you are hitting the target really hard with 20k requests per minute.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate your answer. I just tested it, but it's still 35% slower than using cURL : (

Comment: Then try a system call to `wget --spider`.

Comment: @George Based on your last comments, I would suggest an alternative approach. Please review my edit.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a php function like "file_exists". for more information follow that link 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

or use this

```
$file = 'http://www.abc.com/somefile.jpg';
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);
if($file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
    $exists = false;
}
else {
    $exists = true;
}
```